# function that checks if a number is a float

Tags: python

I currently have this
how can I get it so it checks for a float and uses a while loop

```
def get_float():
    number = input('Input a decimal number ')
    while number != float:
        print('bad input ')
        number = input('Input a decimal number ')
    else:
        return number
        
get_float()
```

right now even if I enter a decimal number it says bad input and asks for another input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string represents a number (float or int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-represents-a-number-float-or-int)

Comment: Just to clarify for you why the code isn't working. When you use the `input` function, regardless if one enters a number or a decimal Python treats it as a string. You'd also want to check the type of the number in the while statment by using `while type(number) != float:`

Comment: What do you mean by "float"?  What about 2, or 17/51 or 2pi? Is `Decimal("0.3") considered a float?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission.

```
def get_float():
    while True:
        number = input('Input a number ')
        try:
            return float(number)
        except ValueError:
            print('\n bad input\n ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = input('Input a decimal number ')
while number != float:
```

This is wrong for a few reasons.

First, `input()` returns a string, so `number` is a string.  It is not a floating point value.

Second, even if `number` were a proper floating point value, it is not equal to `float`, because `float` is a *type object*.

It seems like you really meant `if type(number) != float`.  (But again, that would always be false here, because `number` is a string.)

Comment: Which is normally spelt `isinstance()`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
def get_float():
    while True:
        number = input('Input a decimal number ')
        try:
            if "." in number:
                floatnumber = float(number)
                print(floatnumber)
                break
            else:
                print("invalid number")
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
                
        
get_float()
```